# How to penalize disagreement between two classification loses?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, regularization, loss-functions, multitask-learning

I am working with a multi-head, multi-loss neural network. Each of the two heads is associated with a multi-class classification loss. The losses are combined additively. Assume loss 1 is trained to predict labels `A`, `B`, and `C`. Similarly, loss 2 is trained to predict labels `A`, `D`, `E`.

I want to enforce the condition that loss 1 always predicts `A` when loss 2 predicts `A` and vice versa, such that any deviation, i.e., L1 predicts `A` and L2 predicts `B`, is penalized during the learning process.

My initial thought was maybe using an indicator function of some sort, which I know is not differentiable, so it would have to approximate an indicator. Any thoughts?

Comment: Minimizing $L_1 + L_2$ will also minimize the loss for class A for each loss individually, so it's not clear why you need to take any special steps at all. Remember that loss functions don't *predict* a hard class label; instead, losses measure disagreement between the model's output and the class labels.

Comment: To clarify, each loss is associated with its own classification head. Could it not be the case that each head will have learned contradictory features? My intention is to avoid this edge case.

Comment: If it's not learning from the data, the loss will be larger, compared to the case where the model learns the classes correctly — this is why I don’t think you need to do anything special. Your description doesn’t sound like a problem you’ve encountered in reality. The way to start this line of inquiry is to track the loss components during training, not solely the total loss. This will allow you to asses if the problem exists, and provide hints on how to debug it. As it stands, this sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to do, and how does this weird model help solve it?